# Puppeteer-stream audio capturing only system sound from Zoom, but ignoring voice sounds

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, puppeteer

The problem is Puppeteer stream lib can record audio and it is recording when i am entering to Zoom meeting. However the issue is somehow the voice sounds are not appearing in recording.

1. Puppeteer stream is skipping them. Which i don't think is true.
2. In browser sound appear in some specific way.
   Please help me to record voice conversation in Zoom calls.
   Code:
   https://codeshare.io/j0JRxB
   sound sample:
   I was talking the whole duration. But sound for testing speakers were only recorded at 12sec.
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_gY3rc9Fai19Tbl9QslCzxdBYVtdwKgA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Zoom voice audio somehow passes by .exe request**. I was blocking it in my code, because i didn't want to auto-download zoom app.
Keep that in mind